# BiqQuery JOIN based on specific criteria issue

Tags: join, google-bigquery, duplicates, left-join

I want to join 2 tables:

INTERACTION
taskId
taskDate
taskClientID

TRANSACTION
transactionId
TransactionDate
transactionClientID

Here are the criteria:

- INTERACTION table must be complete:   an interaction may or may not have one or more transactions linked
- On the other hand: one TRANSACTION can only be linked to 1 Interaction if transaction_date - task_date = 0 to 15 days
  ==> in case of multiple matches, the only the record with the transaction closest to the interaction date must be kept

Thanks for your help!

WITH RankedTransactions AS (
SELECT
transactionID,
transactionDate,
transactionClientID,
taskID,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY transactionID ORDER BY ABS(DATE_DIFF(transactionDate, taskDate, DAY))) AS row_num
FROM
Task t2
JOIN
Transaction t1
ON
t1.transactionClientID = t2.taskClientID
WHERE
ABS(DATE_DIFF(t1.transactionDate, t2.taskDate, DAY)) BETWEEN 0 AND 15
)
SELECT
transactionID,
transactionDate,
transactionClientID,
taskID
FROM
RankedTransactions
WHERE
row_num = 1;